# Searching for UTF8 encoded strings in memory

Tags: windbg

Using windbg, is it possible to search for a UTF8 encoded strings in memory. For example I am trying to find the following string in memory:

```
memory contents:       3c 00 64 00 69 00 76 00 20 00 69 00 64 00 3d 00  
corresponding string:  "<.d.i.v. .i.d.=."
```

Is it possible to execute a search function as follows?

```
search "\<d\0x00i\0x00v\0x00 \0x00i\0x00d\0x00=\0x00"
```

where `\0x00` represents `hex 00` in memory.

Comment: That's not UTF-8, incidentally.  Looks like UTF-16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lkd> s -u nt l10000 "cat"
804dcbec  0063 0061 0074 0069 006f 006e 0050 006f  c.a.t.i.o.n.P.o.
804dedfa  0063 0061 0074 0069 006f 006e 0073 0000  c.a.t.i.o.n.s...
804dfa5e  0063 0061 0074 0069 006f 006e 0046 0072  c.a.t.i.o.n.F.r.
804dfb5c  0063 0061 0074 0069 006f 006e 0050 0072  c.a.t.i.o.n.P.r.
```

or for your actual search string

```
lkd> s -u 0 L?10000000 "<div id"
009f582e  003c 0064 0069 0076 0020 0069 0064 0022  <.d.i.v. .i.d.".
009f5924  003c 0064 0069 0076 0020 0069 0064 0022  <.d.i.v. .i.d.".
00a08200  003c 0064 0069 0076 0020 0069 0064 0022  <.d.i.v. .i.d.".
00a0b598  003c 0064 0069 0076 0020 0069 0064 0022  <.d.i.v. .i.d.".
```